# Annoying Cursor in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-kepler, ubuntu-13.04

I have eclipse kepler on Ubuntu 13.04 which has Dark Juno theme and solarized color theme for the editor. It didn't have any problem until recently wherein whenever I'm typing the typing cursor seems to have this black trail that goes with it and covers like 5-6 characters. It also occurs when I'm trying to go into lines of code using mouse or keyboard. It doesn't seem to be the smart insert mode which I've tried turning off and didn't have any effect. Sometimes the typing cursor becomes 2 and I don't have a clue why that happens.

some screenshots(I'm linking cause I don't have enough reputation to post images):

http://s23.postimg.org/586jmlsxm/Screenshot_from_2013_10_29_14_15_41.jpg

http://s23.postimg.org/pprhy9513/Selection_006.png

EDIT:
I've tried reverting to default theme, reverting to text editor default color theme(turned the thing that blocks the text into white), restarting eclipse, and restarting the laptop itself. Nothing worked.

EDIT:
Upon testing creating new projects in C, C++, and java, I found out that the input was fine but with android projects this problem occurs.

Comment: I'm guessing it's got something to do with Compiz (the window manager behind Unity).  Does the same thing happen when you run Eclipse in a different desktop environment (like LXDE or XFCE)?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lxde`.  Then logout and log into the new desktop (not Unity), run Eclipse and see if the same thing happens or not?

Comment: Just finished installing and trying it on LXDE, the behavior of the strange black thing changed. On lxde it doesn't appear when I'm plainly typing, it does however, appear when I'm moving through the code using keyboard or mouse but disappears as soon as I press a key.

Comment: Have you tried with a different colour theme in LXDE (`lxappearance`)?  If that's doesn't work, try it with a fresh Eclipse?

Comment: It seems that it's just lag, whenever I type or erase a key it covers the surrounding text and disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: What is your VGA card?  nVidia?

Comment: yes. I've tried running eclipse with optirun bridged with primus same result. I've tried creating c++, c and java (I'm programming android) and it doesn't seem to occur on those. It only happens to android projects for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the highlighter by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Comment: this works for removing the black thing but then it immediately comes back after typing a character or two.