# Failures in the Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-kepler

I'm using Eclipse Kepler (Build id 20130919-0819) with ADT plugin on Ubuntu (version 13.04) and I'm facing some problems with Eclipse editor that is small but it's really annoying.

Whenever I start to write a small gray block stays over the next characters and I can't see the end of sentence. This block disappear if I save the document (Ctrl+S)

[image: eclipse editor]

Another "glitch" I noted occurs when I try to select form left-to-right.

[image]

Here some things that I tried

- I've tried to change some editor preferences in "Preferences..." window but none work.
- Increase -Xms and -Xmx in eclipse.ini (512 and 2048 respectively)

Comment: Have you tried with a new workspace? Create a new workspace and copy your projects in the workspace folder, then import them as existing projects. This way configurations of the preferences etc. that might have gone wrong are reset.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I created a fresh new workspace and the problem persists. Maybe try another Eclipse version. I'll check.

Comment: Check if it happens in the regular XML Editor and not just the Android Layout Editor.  Also, try it with a different Text Font.

Comment: The same happens with Java editor [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/BXjAifl.png) and with different fonts (in this example I'm using 'inconsolata')

Comment: Somewhat similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651414/annoying-cursor-in-eclipse-kepler)

Comment: Just a very wild guess but you could also try a different JDK. I'm guessing you are using OpenJDK? Try the one from Oracle. I'm using Kepler on 13.04 and don't have that problem. Are you using Unity or another desktop environment?

Comment: I use Unity and OpenJDK (java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64). I switched to xfce4 and apparently the problem disappeared. I'll try to use for some hours and report again.

Comment: After one day using xfce4 I can report that I can use Eclipse daily (I faced some "glitches" but it's acceptable). I don't consider switch to another desktop environment a final answer. I guess this could be considered a workaround. Apparently it's a Ubuntu/Unity failure. I would thank Calon, nitind, greg-449 and @stonedsquirrel for the comments.